# R command-line file dialog? similar to file.choose

Tags: file, r, command-line, explorer

Are there any R users aware of an "open file"-type function in R?
Preferably it'd have a text interface, e.g.:

```
> file.choose("/path/to/start/at")
path/to/start/at:
[1] [D] a_directory
[2] [D] another_directory
[3] [F] apicture.tif
[4] [F] atextfile.txt
...
[..] Go up a directory
Enter selection:
```

And I'd be able to browse through until I select the file(s) I wanted.

I *am* aware of the current `file.choose`, but (on Linux anyway) that just says "enter file name:" and takes whatever you type in, but doesn't give you the ability to browse. (Perhaps on Windows it shows an "open file" dialog?).

I'm amenable to an open file dialog but would prefer to stay away from loading a GUI package like RGtk2/tcltk/etc just for this.

I could also write the above text browser myself but I figured I'd ask to see if anyone knew of such a function before I try to reinvent the wheel (and get it wrong many, many, times before it works!)

cheers.

## Update

The answer is "no" to the text-based interface. But based on @TylerRinker's solution and comments by @Iterator, I wrote my own function to do it (and it was much easier than I thought thanks to them!):

**Edit** - modified default to `multiple=F` as usually people expect to select one file.

```
#' Text-based interactive file selection.
#'@param root the root directory to explore
#'             (default current working directory)
#'@param multiple boolean specifying whether to allow 
#'                 multiple files to be selected
#'@return character vector of selected files.
#'@examples 
#'fileList <- my.file.browse()
my.file.browse <- function (root=getwd(), multiple=F) {
    # .. and list.files(root)
    x <- c( dirname(normalizePath(root)), list.files(root,full.names=T) )
    isdir <- file.info(x)$isdir
    obj <- sort(isdir,index.return=T,decreasing=T)
    isdir <- obj$x
    x <- x[obj$ix]
    lbls <- sprintf('%s%s',basename(x),ifelse(isdir,'/',''))
    lbls[1] <- sprintf('../ (%s)', basename(x[1]))

    files <- c()
    sel = -1
    while ( TRUE ) {
        sel <- menu(lbls,title=sprintf('Select file(s) (0 to quit) in folder %s:',root))
        if (sel == 0 )
            break
        if (isdir[sel]) {
            # directory, browse further
            files <- c(files, my.file.browse( x[sel], multiple ))
            break
        } else {
            # file, add to list
            files <- c(files,x[sel])
            if ( !multiple )
                break
            # remove selected file from choices
            lbls <- lbls[-sel]
            x <- x[-sel]
            isdir <- isdir[-sel]
        }
    }
    return(files)
}
```

It might barf with symlinks and the '..' since I use `normalizePath`, .. but oh well.

Comment: On Windows and on Macs it does give the GUI type browser that you ask about.  I remember the first time using file.choose on Linux... I thought it was useless and wanted some sort of browser!

Comment: I personally don't mind file.choose, but I'm giving this code to some collaborators and the sort of paths they're entering will be very prone to typos, so I just wanted something that will only let them select existing files.

Comment: Combined with shell.exec (I'm a windows user most of the time; so not sure what the equivalent commands are on other OS) this is pretty nice.  Thanks for sharing mathematical coffee.  `shell.exec(my.file.browse())` or `shell.exec(my.file.browse(root = path.expand("~")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have kind of what you want made that I keep in my .Rprofile.  It has a menu interface as it's default for looking through the working directory.  If you want it extended to start with he root directory and work out with menus from there you'd have to do a lot of modifying of the function.

The function finds only .txt  .R and .Rnw files in the menu.

```
Open <- function(method = menu) {
    wd<-getwd()
    on.exit(setwd(wd))

    x <- dir()
    x2 <- subset(x, substring(x, nchar(x) - 1, nchar(x)) == ".R" | 
        substring(x, nchar(x) - 3, nchar(x)) %in%c(".txt", ".Rnw"))

    if (is.numeric(method)) {      
        x4 <- x2[method]
        x5 <- as.character(x4)
        file.edit(x5)
    } else { 
        switch(method, 
            menu = { x3 <- menu(x2)
                     x4 <- x2[x3]
                     x5 <- as.character(x4)
                     file.edit(x5)
                    }, 
            look = file.edit(file.choose()))
    }
}

##########
#Examples
#########
Open()
Open("L")
```

Comment: cheers - I was considering writing a similar function but I'll wait to see if anyone knows of one already - it's just going to be a pain programming in the recursive thing (to explore subfolders, etc). Nice snippet!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Maybe I'm groggy, but I'm not quite getting what you mean about recursion being necessary.  As I see it, you have a state and expect either a selection, which opens an editor, or a while loop, which simply updates a state (i.e. directory and listing) until a selection or an exit is made.

Comment: Ahh @TylerRinker, and thank you so much for pointing me to the `menu` function! I've been doing this manually all this time..!

Comment: I managed to use your code as a base for a file browser function, thanks to you two it turned out much easier than I thought. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use 'menu' but I wanted to be able to display "D" if something was a directory.  It could probably be modified by just adding "D" to the beginning of the string or something but oh well.  This defaults to starting in the current working directory.  There is a lot that could be tweaked and made more robust but this is certainly a start.

```
## File chooser
file.chooser <- function(start = getwd(), all.files = FALSE){
    DIRCHAR <- "D"
    currentdir <- path.expand(start)
    repeat{
        ## Display the current directory and add .. to go up a folder
        display <- c(dir(currentdir, all.files = all.files))
        ## Find which of these are directories
        dirs <- c(basename(list.dirs(currentdir, rec=F)))

        if(!all.files){
            display <- c("..", display)
            dirs <- c("..", dirs)
        }

        ## Grab where in the vector the directories are
        dirnumbers <- which(display %in% dirs)

        n <- length(display)
        ## Create a matrix to display
        out <- matrix(c(1:n, rep("", n), display), nrow = n)
        ## Make the second column an indicator of whether it's a directory
        out[dirnumbers, 2] <- DIRCHAR
        ## Print - don't use quotes
        print(out, quote = FALSE)
        ## Create choice so that it exists outside the repeat
        choice <- ""
        repeat{
            ## Grab users input
            ## All of this could be made more robust
            choice <- scan(what = character(), nmax = 1, quiet = T)
            ## Q or q will allow you to quit with no input
            if(tolower(choice) == "q"){
                return(NULL)
            }
            ## Check if the input is a number
            k <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(choice)))
            if(k){
                break
            }else{
                ## If the input isn't a number display a message
                cat("Please input either 'q' or a number\n")
            }
        }
        ## Coerce the input string to numeric
        choice <- as.numeric(choice)

        if(out[choice, 2] != DIRCHAR){
            ## If the choice isn't a directory return the path to the file
            return(file.path(currentdir, out[choice, 3]))
        }else{
            ## If the input is a directory add the directory
            ## to the path and start all over
            currentdir <- path.expand(file.path(currentdir, out[choice, 3]))
        }
    }
}

file.chooser()
```

Edit: I didn't see your update.  Your function is quite a bit nicer than mine!  You should post yours as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Dason! I ended up writing my own function for this one and it is almost exactly the same as yours :P I just used `menu` to do the selection part so I didn't have to verify the numeric input myself (I did the "modify and add D to beginning of the string"). Sorry I can't choose both of these as answers, but thank you very much :)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee No worries! I had fun writing it.  I edited in a little something right after I submitted it and realized you had wrote your own function.  Your presentation looks nicer than mine and tyler gave you the start so I understand!  When I tried your function out the multiple option threw me for a loop for a second because I thought I did something wrong when I finally selected a file.  It's an interesting idea though to allow selection more than one file.  Do you think the default should be multiple=T though?  It seems to me more often that we only want to select one file.

Comment: Yeah, default should probably be multiple=F - it's just that the need for this function has arisen out of one of my projects in which we always have to select multiple files.